# How to run nodejs express web server on ubuntu server

Tags: node.js, express, ubuntu, webserver

I'm trying to run a Nodejs express Webserver on a ubuntu server.

The problem is that it's not running. The program got 1 route "/" and it returns "Hello world". When I start the program using nodemon i get this log:

```
[nodemon] 1.18.10
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching: *.*
[nodemon] starting `node index.js`
Server started on port 3000
```

And when I run "netstat -na | grep :3000" I get:

```
tcp   0   0 SERVERIPHIDDEN:3000 0.0.0.0:*   LISTEN
```

I'm listening to port 3000 ip is the servers ip.

Anything that I have done wrong? or am I missing a step?

code:

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()

app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 5000))
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))

app.get('/', function(request, response) {
  response.send('Hello World!')
})

app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  console.log("Node app is running at localhost:" + app.get('port'))
})
```

Everything is on digital ocean.

Testing process:

1) pm2 start app.js
Everything starts fine status => online.

2) In putty "curl localhost:5000"
Gets "Hello world!

3) In putt "curl IP:5000"
Gets "Hello world!<

4) In google chrome browser IP:5000
Gets "ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED"

Comment: to workaround try to run the server with node instead of nodemon. it should be something like node <startup script>.

Comment: @JoseMarfil, Thanks for your reply! But this didn't change anything.

Comment: What's wrong with netstat? You are just listening in localhost (not a public ip), and you can contact your http server only from the server itself. That's probably  happening because your http server is specifyng "localhost" as ip when the "listen" function is called. Moreover, listening on port 80 require you to launch the server as root. This will make your server vulnerable.

Comment: @Radar155 I changed the port and changed the ip to the servers ip, but it's still not working..

Comment: try without specifyng any ip address

Comment: @Radar155 Didn't work.

Comment: Please post the webserver code

Comment: @Radar155 Done, please reload.

Comment: nothing special in the code. How are you testing it? I mean, you said "it's not running", why you say that? Did you make a request from a client? Wich client? Browser, curl? In remote? In local? To wich ip/host?

Comment: @Radar155 Please view the update to the question under "Testing process"

Comment: Are you sure "IP" is a public IP? Making curl requests using an ssh connection made by putty (is putty the windows ssh client right?) is basically like making the request from the server itself

Comment: @Radar155 yes, its the inet addr that i get from ifconfig

Comment: that's weird. what about firewalls?

Comment: @Radar155 Not sure how to check that.